# C program to check little vs. big endian

Tags: c, byte, endianness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Macro definition to determine big endian or little endian machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine)

```
int main()
{
  int x = 1;

  char *y = (char*)&x;

  printf("%c\n",*y+48);
}
```

If it's little endian it will print 1.  If it's big endian it will print 0.  Is that correct?  Or will setting a char* to int x always point to the least significant bit, regardless of endianness?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2100331/335858), it may be related.

Comment: @ordinary - Just a note that big endian and little endian are not the only options, that not all data types need to have the same [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and that some hardware can be configured at runtime. If you really need to check this, you might have to check more things.

Comment: If you have the option, consider bitwise operations on fixed width datatypes to extract/set bits. They are portable [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12730780/3041008)

Comment: Great endianness demo code for userland and even a kernel module: https://gitlab.com/eric.saintetienne/endianness

Comment: Why use ASCII. Use `'0'`. Why print as a char and not an int. Why start as an int.

Comment: To answer part of my question, print as `char` so C only reads a byte of data. Start as `int` so that we have multiple bytes and can inspect endianness. Cast to `char` now seems unnecessary, just print as `char`.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

In short, yes.

Suppose we are on a 32-bit machine.

If it is little endian, the `x` in the memory will be something like:

```
       higher memory
          ----->
    +----+----+----+----+
    |0x01|0x00|0x00|0x00|
    +----+----+----+----+
    A
    |
   &x
```

so `(char*)(&x) == 1`, and `*y+48 == '1'`. (48 is the ascii code of '0')

If it is big endian, it will be:

```
    +----+----+----+----+
    |0x00|0x00|0x00|0x01|
    +----+----+----+----+
    A
    |
   &x
```

so this one will be `'0'`.

Comment: What is the significance of the value 48 added to y?

Comment: @AbinMathewAbraham 48 is the ascii code of '0' :)

Comment: I am using MAC OS with intel processors. It is supposed to be Little Endian. However,  `1` seems to be a special case because when `1` is stored inside the memory, it is in big endian.

Comment: @code4j That doesn't make any sense. The CPU architecture isn't going to make an exception simply for a specific value. What you are seeing must be a one byte value, in which case endianess makes no difference. To do an endianess test, you must choose a multi-byte value. Intel chips (AFAIK) are little endian.

Comment: Can you tell me why we can't just use `(char)x == 1` ? Why do we have to get the address, convert it to a `char` pointer and then dereference? Won't this be implicitly done `(char)x` is used?

Comment: @J...S I believe `(char)x` would work regardless of endianness. And by _"work"_, I mean it would assign the value `1` to `x`, so it wouldn't be possible to detect the endianness this way.

Comment: regarding your response:  _"48 is the ascii code of '0'"_. Would it not be useful to update your answer to _"so"_  _`(char*)(&x) == 1, and *y+'0' == '1'`_  ?  (nice answer regardless, +1)

Comment: What about only type casting the variable but not the pointer? Like this: `int x = 1; char y = (char) x` ... It also provides the result as true only, so wondering if it has any drawbacks

Answer (score 27):

The following will do.

```
unsigned int x = 1;
printf ("%d", (int) (((char *)&x)[0]));
```

And setting `&x` to `char *` will enable you to access the individual bytes of the integer, and the ordering of bytes will depend on the endianness of the system.

Comment: No need to declare as unsigned int. signed int also will do because 1 is positive and even if one bit is reserved for sign, it will be 0 anyway for positive numbers.

Answer (score 23):

This is big endian test from a [configure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) script:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    volatile uint32_t i=0x01234567;
    // return 0 for big endian, 1 for little endian.
    return (*((uint8_t*)(&i))) == 0x67;
}
```

Comment: Why volatile instead of const?

Comment: I think it is an easy way to avoid any undesired compiler optimization, and actually look at the data in the ram cell to determine the answer.

Comment: thx, optimization must be suppressed here.

Answer (score 14):

Thought I knew I had read about that in the standard; but can't find it. Keeps looking. Old; answering heading; not Q-tex ;P:

---

The following program would determine that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int is_big_endian(void)
{
    union {
        uint32_t i;
        char c[4];
    } e = { 0x01000000 };

    return e.c[0];
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("System is %s-endian.\n",
        is_big_endian() ? "big" : "little");

    return 0;
}
```

You also have [this approach](https://bitbucket.org/thejeshgn/quake/src/14ba6369f82c/WinQuake/common.c#cl-1125); from Quake II:

```
byte    swaptest[2] = {1,0};
if ( *(short *)swaptest == 1) {
    bigendien = false;
```

And `!is_big_endian()` is not 100% to be little as it can be mixed/middle.

Believe this can be checked using same approach only change value from `0x01000000` to i.e. `0x01020304` giving:

```
switch(e.c[0]) {
case 0x01: BIG
case 0x02: MIX
default: LITTLE
```

But not entirely sure about that one ...

Comment: aren't you forgetting ==1 after e.c[0]

Comment: @Nate: 1 == 1, 1 != 0, !!1 or 1 is the same. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hmm not sure... This isn't my forte. I saw a similar operation but it had the ==1 at the end. So I'm not sure.

Comment: @Nate: Yes. Probably using something like `e = { 0x01020304 };` Then `a.c[0] == 1` would be needed as `a.c[0]` would be `1` or `4` on big- vs little.

Comment: Ah yea that would be it.