# Showing Big/Little Endian?

Tags: c, endianness

I need to write a small *C* program to demonstrate that the *UNIX* operating system is using Big Endian, and the *MS-Windows/DOS* system is using Little Endian. I'm having trouble putting my thoughts into code (beginner coder) but I'm assuming I can load a 32 bit word into an address and just check where the LSB is, but then again I'm still a beginner.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C program to check little vs. big endian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791864/c-program-to-check-little-vs-big-endian)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
   unsigned int i = 1;

   char *c = (char*)&i;

   if (*c) {  
       printf("Little endian");
   } else {
       printf("Big endian");
   }

   getchar();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf ("%s endian\n", *c ? "Little" : "Big");`