# Get binary representation of variables in C

Tags: c

I would like to get a binary representation for all types of variables in C: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `float`, `double` and `char`.

It is the best solution, when I getting the size of a variable (by `sizeof()`) and converting it to the binary system?

How to quickly and easily carry out such a conversion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Comment: They are already in binary.

Comment: Are you wanting a binary conversion function for all these types? Or sizeof() those types? Please clarify a little more of what you need

Comment: Use `sizeof` to determine the size of the type, point an `unsigned char *` to the variable in question, loop through each byte, then use bit shifting to print each bit.

Comment: In a **binary** digital computer, there is no other representation of data than binary.

Comment: @olaf... BCD... little endian, big endian... not to mention different encoding schemes...

Comment: @GradyPlayer I was just thinking how to reply to Olaf, but he is right, BCD is still binary coded, and endianess is not a binary issue.

Comment: ...even floating point encoding schemes are in binary, with various fields within the whole. But I like the dup.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: And which one of them is **not** binary? If you look up what "BCD" means, you will find: **Binary** **C**oded **D**ecimal. Representation != encoding!

Comment: @Olaf some times I forget why I come here...

Answer (score 0):

**Get binary representation of any type:**

I wrote the following code to provide two functions that do what you asked for. The first function `getBinaryHostMemoryRepresentation()` will fill your provided `buffer` with the bits how they are saved in your hosts memory: That could be little-endian, big-endian or something else (unlikely). For example the integer `0xABCD` is saved on a little-endian as `0xCDAB`.

The `getBinaryRepresentation()` function will check on what machine you are running and will fill your `buffer` with the bit representation you would expect as human readable which is big-endian so you would get `0xABCD`. To check on what kind of machine the program is running it uses the `isLittleEndian()` function, see how it works [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791864/c-program-to-check-little-vs-big-endian/12792301#12792301).

Both functions need the following arguments: `char * const buffer, size_t bufSize, const void * var, size_t varSize`. The first two are the buffer and the size of the buffer. The last two are the variable you want to convert (it's a void pointer, it can be any data) and the size in bytes of the variable which can get by `sizeof()`. Further the functions check if the buffer is big enough, if not they're returning a null pointer. If it is big enough they return the pointer to the buffer you provided. The usage could be observed in `main()` function.

The `main()` function uses two inputs for teh functions above:

1. The integer: `2882400235` which is `0xABCDEFEB` or `0b10101011110011011110111111101011`
2. The float: `42.0` which is `0x42280000` or `0b01000010001010000000000000000000`.

To check integers you could use the Windows calculator, to check floats you can use [this site online](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754de.html).

Output of the program:

```
integer 2882400235:
Host memory binary representation:    "11101011111011111100110110101011"
Human readable binary representation: "10101011110011011110111111101011"

single floating point 42.0:
Host memory binary representation:    "00000000000000000010100001000010"
Human readable binary representation: "01000010001010000000000000000000"
```

---

The code in C as you tagged the question with C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>

#if CHAR_BIT != 8
#error "unsupported char size"
#endif

int isLittleEndian ()
{
   static const int num = 1;
   if (1 == *((char *) &num))
   {
      return 1;
   }
   else
   {
      return 0;
   }
}

char * getBinaryHostMemoryRepresentation (char * const buffer, size_t bufSize, const void * var, size_t varSize)
{
   size_t byteIdx;
   size_t bitIdx;

   if (bufSize < varSize * CHAR_BIT + 1)
   {
      return NULL;
   }
   const unsigned char * curByte = (const unsigned char *) var;
   for (byteIdx = 0; byteIdx < varSize; ++byteIdx, ++curByte)
   {
      for (bitIdx = 0; bitIdx < CHAR_BIT; ++bitIdx)
      {
         unsigned char curBit = (*curByte & (1 << ((CHAR_BIT - 1) - bitIdx))) >> ((CHAR_BIT - 1) - bitIdx);
         buffer[byteIdx * CHAR_BIT + bitIdx] = curBit + '0';
      }
   }
   buffer[varSize * CHAR_BIT] = '\0';
   return buffer;
}

char * getBinaryRepresentation (char * const buffer, size_t bufSize, const void * var, size_t varSize)
{
   size_t byteIdx;
   size_t bitIdx;

   if (bufSize < varSize * CHAR_BIT + 1)
   {
      return NULL;
   }

   const unsigned char * curByte;;
   int incByte;
   if (isLittleEndian ())
   {
      curByte = (const unsigned char *) var + (varSize - 1);
      incByte = -1;
   }
   else
   {
      curByte = (const unsigned char *) var;
      incByte = 1;
   }
   for (byteIdx = 0; byteIdx < varSize; ++byteIdx, curByte += incByte)
   {
      for (bitIdx = 0; bitIdx < CHAR_BIT; ++bitIdx)
      {
         unsigned char curBit = (*curByte & (1 << ((CHAR_BIT - 1) - bitIdx))) >> ((CHAR_BIT - 1) - bitIdx);
         buffer[byteIdx * CHAR_BIT + bitIdx] = curBit + '0';
      }
   }
   buffer[varSize * CHAR_BIT] = '\0';
   return buffer;
}

int main ()
{
   int integer = 2882400235; /* 10101011110011011110111111101011 */
   char bufferMemInt[sizeof (integer) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
   char bufferBinInt[sizeof (integer) * CHAR_BIT + 1];

   printf ("integer 2882400235:\n");
   if (getBinaryHostMemoryRepresentation (bufferMemInt,
                                          sizeof (bufferMemInt),
                                          (void *) &integer,
                                          sizeof (integer)))
   {
      printf ("Host memory binary representation:    \"%s\"",
              bufferMemInt);
      printf ("\n");
   }

   if (getBinaryRepresentation (bufferBinInt,
                                sizeof (bufferBinInt),
                                (void *) &integer,
                                sizeof (integer)))
   {
      printf ("Human readable binary representation: \"%s\"",
              bufferBinInt);
      printf ("\n");
   }


   float floating = 42.0; /* 01000010001010000000000000000000 */
   char bufferMemFloat[sizeof (floating) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
   char bufferBinFloat[sizeof (floating) * CHAR_BIT + 1];

   printf ("\n");
   printf ("single floating point 42.0:\n");
   if (getBinaryHostMemoryRepresentation (bufferMemFloat,
                                          sizeof (bufferMemFloat),
                                          (void *) &floating,
                                          sizeof (floating)))
   {
      printf ("Host memory binary representation:    \"%s\"",
              bufferMemFloat);
      printf ("\n");
   }

   if (getBinaryRepresentation (bufferBinFloat,
                                sizeof (bufferBinFloat),
                                (void *) &floating,
                                sizeof (floating)))
   {
      printf ("Human readable binary representation: \"%s\"",
              bufferBinFloat);
      printf ("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @geekcode if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.