# How are ints in c stored in memory?

Tags: c, memory

I thought that ints in C were stored with the most significant bit first, for example, the number `5` would be `0...0101`. I thought I could manipulate specific bits by coercing C to let me pretend a specific memory address was an `int` and adding to the bits there like they were an `int`.

I tried to set up 0 bits of 0s in memory, then tried adding `255` to different memory addresses and it seems to work as though the least significant digit is stored in memory before the most significant digit because when I added 1 to my memory address and changed the bits there I got a larger number instead of a smaller one. If the most significant bit was stored earlier in memory, adding `255` to the memory address 1 byte higher over shouldn't affect the number at the original address at all because the last 8 bits are the beginning of the next `int`. I was wondering if I was interpreting this correctly, and that ints were stored with the least significant bit first.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() {
    int *x = malloc(8); //getting 4 memory addresses
    int *y = malloc(8);
    int *z = malloc(8);
    int *a = malloc(8);

    x[0] = 0; //setting 64 bits past memory addresses to 0s
    x[1] = 0;
    y[0] = 0;
    y[1] = 0;
    z[0] = 0;
    z[1] = 0;
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 0;

    *((int*)((int)x)) = 255; //adding to x's memory address
    *((int*)((int)y + 1)) = 255; //adding 1 byte over from y
    *((int*)((int)z + 2)) = 255; //adding 2 bytes over from z
    *((int*)((int)a + 3)) = 255; //adding 3 bytes over from a

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("%d,%d\n", x[0], x[1]);
    printf("%d,%d\n", y[0], y[1]);
    printf("%d,%d\n", z[0], z[1]);
    printf("%d,%d\n", a[0], a[1]);

    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d\n", &x[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
4
255,0
0,-16777216
0,16711680
0,65280
12784560
12784564
```

Actual Output:

```
4
255,0
65280,0
16711680,0
-16777216,0
12784560
12784564
```

Comment: You have to account for Endianness which is platform specific, see following link for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791864/c-program-to-check-little-vs-big-endian

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. Why all the casts?

Comment: @Max Does this depend on the compiler, the machine, or something else?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I didn't cast the memory address to an int first, the +1 is interpreted at 4 bytes instead of 1, but then I had to cast it back to an int* and dereference it so it was a proper lvalue I could assign 255 to

Comment: Trouble is the "pretense" breaks the rules of the language. At least it would in C++; to be fair I'm not 100% on that in C.

Comment: *If I didn't cast the memory address to an int first ...*  You **can't** cast a pointer to `int` without invoking undefined behavior if you later dereference any resulting "pointer" that you construct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought that ints in c were stored with the most significant bit first, for example, the number 5 would be 0...0101

No, this depends on your platform & toolchain, not on C.

The scheme you describe (almost) is called *big-endian*.

Many commodity PCs nowadays are [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian), so the opposite (least significant byte first). This may be the case for you.

Note that endianness talks about *bytes*, not bits.

It would be better not to try to manipulate data like this. Work with the language, using logical operations that don't care about endianness.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code:

- there seems to be some confusion between *bit* and *byte*. Computer memory is addressable as bytes, usually comprising 8 bits on current architectures.
- you should not cast pointer to `int`, `int` might not have enough range to accommodate for a pointer's value. convert the pointers to `unsigned char *` to patch individual bytes, but be aware that this might not yield the expected results due to the aliasing rule:

  ```
  ((unsigned char *)x)[0] = 255; //adding to x's memory address
  ((unsigned char *)y)[1] = 255; //adding 1 byte over from y
  ((unsigned char *)z)[2] = 255; //adding 2 bytes over from z
  ((unsigned char *)a)[3] = 255; //adding 3 bytes over from a
  ```
- Similarly, you should use `%zu` to print a `size_t` or convert the `size_t` to `int`.
- pointers should be cast as `(void*)` and printed with `%p`.
- the effect of your changes would be more obvious if printing the `int` values in hex.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // getting 4 memory addresses, each with enough space for 2 int, initialized to 0
    int *x = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
    int *y = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
    int *z = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
    int *a = calloc(2, sizeof(int));

    ((unsigned char *)x)[0] = 255; //adding to x's memory address
    ((unsigned char *)y)[1] = 255; //adding 1 byte over from y
    ((unsigned char *)z)[2] = 255; //adding 2 bytes over from z
    ((unsigned char *)a)[3] = 255; //adding 3 bytes over from a

    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(int));
    printf("%08x,%08x -- %d,%d\n", x[0], x[1], x[0], x[1]);
    printf("%08x,%08x -- %d,%d\n", y[0], y[1], y[0], y[1]);
    printf("%08x,%08x -- %d,%d\n", z[0], z[1], z[0], z[1]);
    printf("%08x,%08x -- %d,%d\n", a[0], a[1], a[0], a[1]);

    printf("%p\n", (void *)x);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&x[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
000000ff,00000000 -- 255,0
0000ff00,00000000 -- 65280,0
00ff0000,00000000 -- 16711680,0
ff000000,00000000 -- -16777216,0
0x7fd42ec02630
0x7fd42ec02634
```

From the above output, we can see that:

- type `int` has 4 bytes
- pointers use 8 bytes (my environment is 64-bit, unlike yours)
- `int` are stored with the lowest significant byte first, same as yours, which is called *little-endian architecture*.

You were expecting the opposite, *big-endian architecture*, which is quite rare on current desktop and laptop computers, but very common on embedded architectures and mobile phones.

Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages. C supports both transparently, so most programmers are not aware of these intricacies, yet understanding these implementation details is very useful in some situations:

- systems programming, low level programming, device driver development,
- image processing
- reading and writing binary files and streams,
- handling network transmission of binary data, especially to and from different devices.
- interfacing with other programming languages, writing libraries, etc.