# variable bitwise operation in c

Tags: c, binary

I have a list of variables, notice each of them has only one `1` in distinct position in binary form:

```
int a = 0x00000001;
int b = 0x00000002;
int c = 0x00000004;
int d = 0x00000008;
int bounder = d;
int e = 0x00000010;
int f = 0x00000020;
```

A new variables X can be set to `bitwise OR` of any variables in above like:

`int X = a | b | d | f;`

I need a function `f` to check a given `X(X >= bounder)`, does it `bitwise OR` variables which value < bounder. For example:

```
f(a|d) return true
f(a|b|c|e) return true
f(e|f) return false
```

I write:

```
bool f(int x) {
    return x << 29;
}
```

But 29 is a hard code, if I change bounder value, I can not forget to change 29 aslo. And I am not sure this is cross platform(the int binary representation may different?)

I'd need f to:

1. run fast.
2. cross platform ( linux and windows ).
3. bounder value can change to another variable like c or e... (runtime, at least compile-time)

Comment: `x << 29` yields an integer, not a `bool`. You would have to write the function as `return (x << 29) != 0;`. Also, if `x` is negative your code invokes undefined behavior. When doing bitwise operations, there is no reason why you would want to use `int` instead of `uint32_t` or a similar unsigned type.

Comment: `return ((x & (bounder - 1)) != 0)`

Comment: @kaylum. great! This is what I want. Could you answer this question?

Comment: @Lundin, yes, I find http://stackoverflow.com/a/12730780/851185. shift a signed number is not cross platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether any bit in `x` is set that is less than `bounder` do:

```
bool f(unsigned int x, unsigned int bounder)
{
    return ((x & (bounder - 1)) != 0);
}
```

The `-1` is the key as it results in a mask that has all the bits that need to be checked set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understant your requirements, this does the job

```
bool f(int x, int upper_bound)
{
    return x < upper_bound;
}
```

Comment: @SimonKraemer I did, thx.

Comment: f(a|b|c|e) return true?